# Is there a better way to swap/update an ArrayList which is inside a Map for Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

My Superclass has a `HashMap` "M" whose values are an ArrayList and keys range from 0 - N based on a matrix. I have created a method called swap() in a subclass which takes the ArrayList of a specific row "x" (Map's Key) and swaps it with another row "y". Below is roughly how my swap() method is:

```
public void swap(int currentRow, int hRow ) {
    ArrayList <Double> temp = new ArrayList<Double>(super.M.get(hRow));
    M.put(hRow, super.M.get(currentRow));\\from super
    M.put(currentRow, temp);\\ from super
}
```

This definitely does the job I want but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way? Especially can you do the same without creating the Array "temp" i.e by just using java Map functions?

**Edit 1:**
I understand there is a way to do the above without creating a new ArrayList, but what if let's say I want to the multiply values in an ArrayList with a constant like 2 and update that particular ArrayList on the map after doing so, can I still do it without creating a temporary Array?

Comment: Why not putting `super.M.get(hRow)` directly, if it's an arraylist? Why you need the temp assignment?

Comment: Your question involves the `ArrayList` as just another opaque `Object`. No need to detail anything about it and the question is just about swapping values in map keys. Also class hierarchy plays no role in the question, just another distraction.

Comment: @ceeks Re: **Edit 1**: In that case it's a completely different question. The answers below answer the *actual* question you asked.

Comment: @Thomas I'll create another thread!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create an extra ArrayList `temp`, then don't do it:

```java
public void swap(int currentRow, int hRow ) {
    ArrayList<Double> temp = super.M.get(hRow);
    super.M.put(hRow, super.M.get(currentRow));
    super.M.put(currentRow, temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to create a new `ArrayList`, you can do:

```
ArrayList<Double> temp = super.M.get(hRow);
super.M.put(hRow, super.M.get(currentRow));
super.M.put(currentRow, temp);
```

Or, given that `put` returns the old value, you can even write:

```
ArrayList<Double> temp = super.M.put(hRow, super.M.get(currentRow));    
super.M.put(currentRow, temp);
```

or even:

```
super.M.put(currentRow, super.M.put(hRow, super.M.get(currentRow)));
```